# Which is the best method to compare two dates in YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

Which of the following is the best method to compare two date values in the format(YYYY-MM-DD)? Both methods produces the same output in the following example. One of my date is comming from the database and which is in YYYY-MM-DD format and i am using mysql too.

### Method 1

```
$d1 = '2014-01-01';
$d2 = '2014-01-02';
if($d1 > $d2)
  echo 'D1 is big';
else
  echo 'D2 is big';
```

### Ouptput

> D2 is big

### Method 2

```
$d1 = '2014-01-01';
$d2 = '2014-01-02';
if(strtotime($d1) > strtotime($d2))
  echo 'D1 is big';
else
  echo 'D2 is big';
```

### Output

> D2 is big

Is the comparison depends upon the verison of php? My php version is 5.5.5

Comment: Can you explain the reason

Comment: What if your dates are like `Jan 1 2014` and `Dec 10 2014`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Method 2 is better.

Comment: It wont be like that it will be only in `YYYY-MM-DD` format @Barmar

Comment: That's not what the question says. It only says "same format", not "this specific format".

Comment: Also checked with what you mentioned in the last comment. But it also gives the correct result @Barmar.My php version is 5.5.5

Comment: I think it might be best to use runtime variables against them to tell which is quicker. true test

Comment: Method 2 is explicit and less ambiguous than method 1. Even if method 1 is faster, we may have a look at good coding practices.

Comment: Method 3 can be to compare DateTime objects. Still, I would use method based on my current situation. If I have dates in format `Y-m-d`, I would not convert them to timestamp or DateTime objects (method 3) just for a compare. Same applies for other methods, if I had dates in timestamp I would not convert them to string or DateTime object just for compare...

Comment: date could be in any format, these above two methods are not sufficient for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If and only if your dates are in YYYY-MM-DD format you can safely compare them string wise.

**It is known and often used property of that format.**

*(First method compares them treating variables as strings)*

If format can differ you should use strtotime ( and make sure it actually is time after and not FALSE)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare dates correctly you need to ensure that they are date objects or timestamps. Knowing this method 1 is the wrong way to go about it.

Using method 2, strtotime would ensure its correct as you're then comparing times.

If you have dates in a different format you will need to input the format of the date.